# Wordpress hook (the_post) slows down Webseite

Tags: php, wordpress, hook, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-hook

I have built an evaluation website. I have created the ratings as a custom post_type. And connected them via a field containing the post_id of the rating object.

With the following script, I want to build an overall rating. And store this in an ACF field of the rating post. So far this works.

The problem is that the `add_action('the_post', 'qualitaet');` query runs permanently and overloads the server with several thousand posts. The hook
`add_action('save_post', 'qualitaet');` does not work either, because you would have to save the post again and again.

Do you have a solution how I can update the post rating with as few queries as possible? Is there maybe a hook that does this or do I have to build something myself? If so, how would you proceed?

```
function qualitaet($post_id)
{
    
$theid = get_the_ID();
    
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'post_type'         => 'reviews',
    'post_status'       => 'publish',
    'meta_key'          => 'nr-id-bewertung',
    'meta_value'        =>  $theid,
);
    
$count = new WP_Query($args);
$the_count = $count->post_count;
    
    
$ratings = get_posts(array(    
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'post_type'         => 'reviews',
    'post_status'       => 'publish',
    'meta_key'          => 'nr-id-bewertung',
    'meta_value'        =>  $theid,
));

$total = 0;
$post_ids =$ratings;

    
    
//update rating leistungen

    
foreach ($ratings as $post) {
  $totalleistungen += (int) get_post_meta($post->ID, 'leistungen-reviews', true);
}
    
if(0 == $the_count)
{
    $theaverageleistungen = "0";
}

else
{
    $theaverageleistungen = round(($totalleistungen/$the_count),1);
}   



//update Unternehmensbewertungen
    

update_field('alle-bewertungen-leistungen', $theaverageleistungen, $post_id);

    
}
add_action('the_post', 'qualitaet');
```

Comment: Why are you updating the rating each time the post data has been setup, this can happen a lot of time on a single page load. Also, you're running 2 similar queries in the same call. You need to make sure this is only associated with user action, not post load.

Comment: I’m not sure exactly what you are doing, but the first parameter supplied to `the_post` hook’s callback is a `WP_Post` object, not an ID. You should inspect this object immediately to determine if it is one you are interested in because it might be another entity such as a Page or a Post. But otherwise, do you really need to update anything? Can you just calculate your rating dynamically on render?

Comment: You are doing this in a very ineffective way. First of all if you want to store average, you should save it only on vote, not every time you're getting the post. Next, having thousands of `reviews` might produce thousands of `get_post_meta` calls and thousands of DB queries, what will be really slow. The solution is to construct a single SQL query calculating all you need manually and exec it via `$wpdb` object.